# Алгоритм для подсчета максимальной последовательности в строке по заданному правилу

Tags: алгоритм

Есть правило для подсчета максимальной последовательности из строки (строка состоит из английский букв и цифр):

Выбирается n-ое количество границ внутри строки, таким образом чтобы перед каждым было число. Далее длина строки внутри каждой из границ умножается на число перед ней. И суммируется с остальными. Нужно определить какая максимальная строка может получится.

Пример для наглядности:
Для строки `'10j19k87d'` максимальная длина получится равна `10*4+87*1=127.`
Оптимальное расположение границ: `10[j19b]87[d]`
Можно конечно расположить и таким образом: `10[j]19[b]87[d]`, но тогда длина будет равна `10*1+19*1+87*1=116`, что меньше предыдущей.

Пробовал решить перебором, не проходит по времени (ограничение 1 секунда, а максимальное количество символов 10^5)

Подскажите подход, который позволит сократить время вычислений

Comment: Звучит, как задача на динамику...

Answer (score 1):

Это типичная задача на [динамическое программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Решил я её соответствующим образом:

```
def is_digit(c):
    return ord(c) >= ord('0') and ord(c) <= ord('9')

def is_num(s):
    for i in s:
        if not is_digit(i):
            return False

    return True

def get_next(a, idx):
    for i in range(idx + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > a[idx]:
            return i

    return -1

s = input()
if is_num(s):
    print(int(s[:-1]))
    exit(0)


nums = []
letters = []

temp = ''
flag = False
for c in s:
    if is_digit(c):
        temp += c
    else:
        if len(temp) > 0:
            nums.append(int(temp))
            temp = ''
            flag = False

        if flag:
            letters[-1] += 1
        else:
            letters.append(1)
            flag = True

#print(nums, letters)

l = len(letters)
dp = [0] * l
dp[0] = nums[0] * letters[0]
idx = 0
length = 0
nxt = -1
for i in range(1, l):
    if i < nxt:
        continue

    if nums[i] > nums[idx]:
        #idx = i
        nxt = get_next(nums, i)
        temp_len = 0
        if nxt == -1:
            nxt = len(nums)

        temp_len = sum(letters[i:nxt]) + sum([len(str(j)) for j in nums[i + 1: nxt]])
        #print(i, nxt, temp_len)

        first = nums[idx] * (letters[i] + len(str(nums[i])))
        second = nums[i] * temp_len

        if first > second:
            dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + first
        else:
            dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + second
            idx = i
    else:
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + nums[idx] * (letters[i] + len(str(nums[i])))

print(max(dp))
```

Как мне кажется, код говорит сам за себя: разобьём строку на блоки чисел и других символов: `nums`, `letters`. `dp[i]` - *ответ для блока с индексом* `i`, очевидно, что `dp[0]` будет равен первому числу умноженному на первую подстроку символов (других вариантов просто нет), далее будем считать ответ для очередного блока перебрав *2 варианта*:

*Продолжить предыдущую серию, то есть 10b19b -> 10[b19b]*
*Начать новую серию, то есть 10b19b -> 10[b] + 19[b]*

[Жадно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC) выбираем наиболее подходящий вариант и переходим к следующему блоку.

### Примечание

Код написан с целью максимально быстрой работы программы, а также понятности для новичков, поэтому не использовал слишком много встроенных функций и одно строчных выражений.

Кроме того, подразумевается, что входная строка будет иметь вид **[число], [строка], [число], [строка]**, иначе не понятно, *как считать ответ для такой строки*.

### Edit

Нашёл тест, при котором программа давала неправильный ответ. Дело в том, что жадно проверять нужно *не до следующего числа по строке*, а до следующего числа, *большего чем текущее*. Код поменял!

Comment: А не может быть так, что жадный анализ первого и второго блока сказал вам делать `10[b19b]`, но на самом деле надо было оставить `10[b]`, а второй блок объединять с третьим?

Comment: @AnT Да, поэтому в цикле проверка на следующее число. Если честно, мне трудно рассуждать без тестов, если найдёте тест с неверным ответом, киньте в комментарии, и я исправлю. Но решение кажется мне правильным в целом: если мы уже нашли ответ для отрезка [0; i-1], то оно уже не будет меняться, а переход можно выполнять за O(1)

Comment: @AnT Только что проверил код и нашёл ошибку. Сейчас выложу исправленный код, спасибо!